# Best way EF Code First Trigger support

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers, ef-code-first

I think there were several similar question that I have now, but I am really confused about googling and reading them now. As I have a Code First approach, and I added migration support, updated to a database, and now I need some nasty stuff, like triggers, stored procedures and views. As far as I understand this, I need to write the SQL create triggers and create stored procedure as strings into my C# Code First code. But where? Where I need to add them (as static or const strings)? Need I write the drop triggers/stored procs strings as well? And how to integrate them into the next migration step? Do anybody know a really helpful step-by-step blog about this topic?

I got an advice as generate the next migration step with the "add-migration" command, then update the Up() and Down() methods with the trigger definitions. That's clear but a little bit away from the code first's point of view, I am afraid of that the table definition and the table triggers (and stored procedures) will be separated. Another advice says to override the context OnModelCreating()... but I can't see when it will execute, how to link to a specific migration step...

And please do not argue about "using a trigger is a stupid thing", as my question is wider than this... how to add any advanced sql server "object" to a code first which is not easy to define in C# as a code first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem recently and the best solution I found was to run the script from an (initially) empty migration. I put the script in a file and added it to the project as a resource.

One interesting trick I had to do is to put special separators in the script file because the GO statement is not a T-SQL statement. I used the term GO--BATCH-- as a batch separator so that it works both in SQL Server Management studio and in code. In code I simply split the script by this separator and run multiple queries like this:

```
public partial class CodeHostDiscovery : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        var batches = Properties.Resources.CodeHostDiscoverySqlScript.Split(new string[] {"GO--BATCH--"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
        foreach (var batch in batches)
        {
            Sql(batch);    
        }
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

Here is a snippet from the SQL script:

```
CREATE SCHEMA SystemServices

GO--BATCH--

CREATE TABLE [SystemServices].[HeartbeatConfiguration] (
```

I don't expect Code First to provide better facilities to do this, because the idea behind Code First is that you don't need stored procedures, triggers or anything else. You just use Code First. That doesn't always hold water of course, and for that you can run SQL on the database.

Comment: Ahm... so you suggest adding new code to Up() method directly. But you must define different script files to each migration, when (for example) you want to define additional triggers later? And you store the trigger definitions away from the code first source code... I see advantages and disadvantages... But thanks for the answer! :)